# how to recursively find if object key exist?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I have the following object

```
acn: "02 0002 0002"
id: "random"
name: "random"
parent_domain: "parent-random"
subDomainData: {random-l3.1: {…}}
sub_domains: ["random-l3.1"]
timestamp: 1549597441
```

and subDomainData is another object that could exist or not.
If it exist it can have another subDomainData, which can have one or some children, or not, and so on.

My doubt is how to create a function to check it recursively, and if true, push its object to another array;
The expected final array would be something like this:

```
[
    {
      acn: "02 0002 0002"
      id: "random"
      name: "random"
      parent_domain: ""
      sub_domains: ["random-l3.1"]
      timestamp: 1549597441
    },
    { // this object would be the result of the parent subDomainData Object.
      acn: "02 0002 0002"
      id: "random-sub-1"
      name: "random-sub-1"
      parent_domain: "parent-random"
      sub_domains: ["random-l3.3"]
      timestamp: 1549597441
    }
  ]
```

right now I am following this approach, that proved to be insufficient:

```
formatDomainList = () => {
const { domain } = this.props;
const domainList = Object.values(domain.subDomainData);
domainList.map(item => (
  Object.keys(item.subDomainData).length && (
    domainList.push(item.subDomainData)
  )
  //etc
  //etc
));
// console.log('domain list', domainList);
```

}

Comment: Doesn't look like you're recursively calling `formatDomainList`

Comment: @CertainPerformance edited, sorry.

Comment: could you provide the complete object through jsonblob.com or something

Comment: @VarunTheFalcon https://jsonblob.com/bf6666f1-3345-11e9-972c-450e90db747a here it is.

Comment: I doubt if you can make recursive function calls using fat arrow function. My recommendation would be to write normal function and call it recursively. And break the recursion if subDomainData attribute is not present for the given object. In which case, there is no child object. HTH.

Comment: @SagarAgrawal do u have an example ?

Comment: Can you share your object, how it looks like, may be just 1 level deep is fine for me to write sample code?

Comment: @SagarAgrawal jsonblob.com/bf6666f1-3345-11e9-972c-450e90db747a here it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this will work for you:

```
//This is your original object
var someObject = {
  acn: "02 0002 0002",
  id: "random",
  name: "random",
  parent_domain: "parent-random",
  subDomainData: { someObjectWith_subDomainData },
  sub_domains: ["random-l3.1"],
  timestamp: 1549597441
 };
 //This will store the list of subDomains in this global variable.
 var subDomainList = [];

 function getSubDomainList(objectToLoop){

  if(objectToLoop.hasOwnProperty('subDomainData')){
    var numOfItems = Object.keys(objectToLoop.subDomainData).length;
    var keys = Object.keys(objectToLoop.subDomainData);
    for(var i = 0; i< numOfItems; i++){
        var key = keys[i];
        var obj = objectToLoop.subDomainData[key];
        subDomainList.push(obj);
        getSubDomainList(obj);
    }
   }
   return;
 }

 getSubDomainList(someObject);
 //The subDomainList will have the array of objects.
```

Comment: just now edited my solution above based on your JSON. your subDomainData is an object which can have multiple keys. And each object for those keys would in-turn have subDomainData. just modified my code to make it work. Try this. Tweak it a little bit so it works for you. I haven't run the code for your JSON but it should work.

Comment: sorry to say, but this code won't work... for the given JSON data the result array should have 4 objects... your code only gives 3 objects as output which doesnt include the parent one "_id": "domains/8999693"

Answer (score 0):

your data format is wrong i guess, wrapped the first object inside a property gave me your desired output

```js
var sourceObj = {
  "till-11.1": {
    _id: "domains/8999693",
    _key: "8999693",
    _rev: "_YFjlOei--_",
    acn: "01 0001 0001",
    activated: false,
    id: "till",
    name: "Till Payments",
    timestamp: 1549838701,
    sub_domains: ["till-l2.1", "till-l2.2"],
    parent_domain: null,
    subDomainData: {
      "till-l2.1": {
        _id: "domains/8999741",
        _key: "8999741",
        _rev: "_YFgLFKW--_",
        acn: "02 0002 0002",
        activated: false,
        id: "till-l2.1",
        name: "Till l2-1",
        timestamp: 1549597441,
        sub_domains: ["till-l3.1"],
        parent_domain: "till",
        subDomainData: {
          "till-l3.1": {
            _id: "domains/9001753",
            _key: "9001753",
            _rev: "_YFghVqi--_",
            acn: "",
            activated: true,
            id: "till-l3.1",
            name: "till l3.1",
            timestamp: 1549598900,
            sub_domains: [],
            parent_domain: "till-l2.1",
            subDomainData: {},
            accessDomains: []
          }
        },
        accessDomains: ["till-l3.1"]
      },
      "till-l2.2": {
        _id: "domains/8999780",
        _key: "8999780",
        _rev: "_YFgLcri--_",
        acn: "02 0002 0002",
        activated: false,
        id: "till-l2.2",
        name: "Till l2-2",
        timestamp: 1549597465,
        sub_domains: [],
        parent_domain: "till",
        subDomainData: {},
        accessDomains: []
      }
    },
    accessDomains: ["till-l2.1", "till-l2.2", "till-l3.1"]
  }
};

var result = [];

const checkSubDomainData = obj => {
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
    if (obj[key].subDomainData !== {}) {
      let innerObjs = obj[key].subDomainData;
      delete obj[key].subDomainData;
      result.push(obj[key]);
      checkSubDomainData(innerObjs);
    } else {
      return;
    }
  });
};

checkSubDomainData(sourceObj);

console.log(result);
```